# Active check if Debian is updated

Tags: zabbix

I have a problem with active checking. I need to check if my debian servers are updated. Pasive check is allready working but I try active checks for first time. I inserted into zabbix_agentd.conf user parameter

```
 UserParameter=system.sw.debianupdates,apt-get dist-upgrade -s  |sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\+\) upgraded.*/\1/p'
```

and set ServerActive(same like server for passive), RefreshActiveChecks(120)

I created an item http://prntscr.com/6jyvww

If I check values in latest data in graph there are no value(no data) but if I try

```
zabbix_get -s IP -k system.sw.debianupdates
```

on zabbix server I get a value which I expected

Any idea what i forgoted set up or I have mistake in?

Comment: If you look at Zabbix agent log with DebugLevel=4, do you see the agent asking the server for checks and do you see the server responding successfully? Does grepping that log for "system.sw.debianupdates" show anything?

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, problem were in service started with another configuration file. Now is working perfectly